# A number sequence problem involving binomial transform.

Tags: number-theory, integer-sequences

Let $\{b_n\}_{n\geq0}$ be a sequence of numbers such that $b_nb_{n+1}=0$, and define
$$a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}b_k.$$
If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, can we conclude that $b_n=0$ for all $n$?

I have tried many special $\{b_n\}$ but neither of them makes $\{a_n\}$ convergent. I think it’s a nontrivial problem.

More generally, if  $\{b_n\}_{n\geq0}$ is a sequence with infinitely many zeros and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, can we still conclude that $b_n=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Nice question! Welcome to MSE. I am afraid your question is likely to be closed if you do not provide some context, motivation, and what you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the context? This is quite easily solved with the right formula..

Comment: The question is interesting so it would be sad to have it closed because you didn't explain what you did to solve the problem.

Comment: @BillO'Haran I have tried many special $\{b_n\}$ but neither of them makes $\{a_n\}$ convergent. I don't think this can be easily solved, can you provide a proof?Thank you.

Comment: @Taladris Thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Thank you for your notice, I have edited the question.

Comment: Could you please give a couple examples of such sequences that you have tried?

Comment: @person first I let $b_n=0$ for odd $n$, then let $b_n=n, n+1, 2^n, 1/2^n, (-2)^n,…$ for even $n$. Also I tried $b_n=0$ when $n$ is not divided by 3,4,5,…

Comment: I am not sure how to solve the problem but here are two ideas (since no one answered it yet): 1) since $a_n$ is an integer for every $n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ is equivalent to $a_n=0$ for $n$ large enough (there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N \implies a_n=0$). 2) You can probably express $b_n$ as a sum involving $a_k$ (something like $b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a_k$). You could have a look at Pascal matrix.

Comment: A solution is posted here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425948